# How to define target table in MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

how to fetch user name with user ID?

Suppose I have 3 tables like this and `user.type holds` *'e'* for employer and *'w'* for worker.

'e' says that user name is on `employer.name` and so 'w' says that user name is in `worker.name`.

[image]

employer.id and worker.id are foreign key of user.id.

Is there any way to get user name while having user id (we don't know type yet) with a single query?

Although if there's a problem with this kind of modeling let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question directly,

```
SELECT  a.*,
        IF(a.type = 'e', b.Name, c.Name) PersonName
FROM    User a
        LEFT JOIN Employer b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
        LEFT JOIN Worker c
            ON a.ID = c.ID
```

Actually, you can redesign the schema and needing only two tables, the `Person` and `Type`

**Type**

- ID (*PK*)
- TypeName

**Person**

- ID (*PK*)
- Name
- UserTypeID (*FK*)

and you can easily get the type for every person,

```
SELECT  a.*,
        b.TypeName
FROM    Person a
        INNER JOIN Type b
            ON a.UserTypeID = b.ID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

---

## SAMPLE RECORDS

**TYPE**

```
╔════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║ TYPENAME ║
╠════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ Employee ║
║  2 ║ Worker   ║
╚════╩══════════╝
```

**PERSON**

```
╔════╦═════════╦════════════╗
║ ID ║  NAME   ║ USERTYPEID ║
╠════╬═════════╬════════════╣
║  1 ║ Stacky  ║          2 ║
║  2 ║ Horton  ║          1 ║
║  3 ║ Alam Na ║          1 ║
║  4 ║ Aw aw   ║          2 ║
╚════╩═════════╩════════════╝
```

**OUTPUT AFTER THE QUERY HAS BEEN EXECUTED**

```
╔════╦═════════╦════════════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║  NAME   ║ USERTYPEID ║ TYPENAME ║
╠════╬═════════╬════════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ Stacky  ║          2 ║ Worker   ║
║  2 ║ Horton  ║          1 ║ Employee ║
║  3 ║ Alam Na ║          1 ║ Employee ║
║  4 ║ Aw aw   ║          2 ║ Worker   ║
╚════╩═════════╩════════════╩══════════╝
```

Comment: Thank you. isn't it  IF(a.type = 'e', b.Name, c.Name) PersonName, You wrote  IF(a.type = 'e', a.Name, b.Name) PersonName

Comment: curious, did you use the first query or you redesign the table? hehe

Comment: Thanks, you answered one of my oldest problems! Actually worker and employer tables are not the same, I think there's no way to redesign it in another way. thanks for your consideration

Comment: you're welcome `:D` glad it helped. you didn't answer my question :D

Comment: I think there's no way to redesign!